# Is it possible to use the SonarQube LDAP plugin with Raduis?

Tags: iis, ldap, sonarqube

We are using SonarQube from past 2 years and mapped it with Active Directory (AD) credentials using below settings

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin

Now we have moved to Amazon Cloud where Infra team told that Ldap will not work for some reason so either we need to use IIS ReverseProxy or something called Radius (may not be correct spell).

For IIS ReverseProxy, we need to restrict access to single IP address, How can we do that ?

For Radius, if somebody has more info on how to configure AD with SonarQube, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is simply no !